# HashMap.containsKey() - how to search for a class?

Tags: java, search, hashmap

Hello
if you search in an `HashMap<String,String>` for a specific value of a key-value-pair, you can write the following:

```
myHashMap.containsKey(myString);
```

But how can I manage it if the key is not a string? I have a class which looks like this:

```
public class Kategorie implements Comparable {
    private String name;

    public Kategorie()  {
        super();
    }

    public Kategorie(String name)  {
        setName(name);
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Object o) {
        if (!(o instanceof Kategorie))  
           throw new ClassCastException();

        Kategorie k = (Kategorie)o;
        String name = k.getName();
        return this.getName().compareTo(name);

    }
}
```

In a map I saved keys and values of this type "Kategorie".

```
mapKategorieDEundEN.put(new Kategorie(strName_de), new Kategorie(strName_en));
```

Later in the code, I want to check if there is a key with a specific string.

```
if (mapKategorieDEundEN.containsKey(searchString))  {
```

...doesn't work, because the key is not a string but a "Kategorie", that's clear.

Then I tried something like this:

```
if (mapKategorieDEundEN.containsKey(new Kategorie(searchString)))  {
```

...doesn't work too. I assume that it doesn't find anything because the object is not the "original" object but a new one.

In this case, can I use containsKey at all or do I have to use a loop over the HashMap?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You class should override [equals](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) and [hashCode](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29), it will work after that.

The HashMap/Hashtable puts the items in "buckets" by using the hashCode of the key, so a new object that represents the same value as another object, and which should be considered as the same object must return the same hashCode. All keys that return the same hashCode will then be considered as candidates, and equals will be invoked on them. It's considered a match if equals returns true.

Comment: I think I down-voted, because although your answer wasn't "wrong", the problem has nothing to do with HashMap specifically, nor how HashMap uses equals and hashcode (that's just one implementation). It is a general contract that all Collections require from their elements. You answer should have addressed the importance of OVERRIDING these two methods, not how they are used deep in the bowls of one java.util class. See my answer.

Comment: +1 for equals and hashcode , And to make it work do ensure that in equals method you check some field values of Kategorie i.e name. Btw from you use case even String as key should work as your Kategorie class only has one member field.

Comment: @Vineet if they do not comment the downvote, they are getting -1 too, anyway it happens to everybody hit and run.

Comment: @Bohemian. That's _wrong_ there's nothing that says that Collections require that you override equals/hashCode, and some collections e.g. ArrayList, LinkedList, Vector don't care about hashCodes. It's also up to you as a developer to specify if you want two different instances, with equal values, to be considered as the same instance or not.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It seems to work when I override those methods in Kategorie like this:
 `@Override
 public int hashCode()  {
  return 1234567890;
 }`

and

 `@Override
 public boolean equals(Object obj)  {
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (obj == this)
            return true;
        if (obj.getClass() != getClass())
            return false;
        
        Kategorie k = (Kategorie)obj;
        return (k.getName() != null && this.getName() != null && k.getName().equals(this.getName()));
 }`

Comment: @Bevor. Glad that it works, but you would probably change the implementation of hashCode. The performance of the HashMap degrades if all keys return the same hashCode. Don't know if you are using Eclipse, but eclipse can generate a good implemenation of hashCode and equals.

Comment: You should include the fields that you used for the equals method also in the hashcode method. If you use Eclipse, i suggest to use the wizard to generate hashcode and equals (right click, then Source -> Generate hashcode and equals). I'm sure, other IDEs have also a wizard for this.

Answer (score 1):

HashMap uses `hashCode()` and `equals()`. You have to implement them. If you don't know how. Check your IDE (eclipse) usually can generate them for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access your objects using your `compareTo` method, you should not use a hashCode/equals based Map, but a SortedMap, like TreeMap (or ConcurrentSkipListMap).

This has the added benefit that it enables range-based queries (e.g. "give me all categories larger than this one"), but is a bit slower (O(log n) instead of O(1)) for simple `get` accesses compared to hash-based access (with a good hash code, not a constant one).

For a general use class, defining both hashCode/equals and compareTo would be sensible, then the user of the class can decide which type of map to use. (If there are different ways to sort your objects, better provide different Comparator objects.)

As a side remark, you should not implement `Comparable`, but `Comparable<Kategorie>`. Then your `compareTo` method would look like this:

```
public int compareTo(Kategorie k) {
    String name = k.getName();
    return this.getName().compareTo(name);
}
```